# Power Apps ComboBox won't allow user to add a new option

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, powerapp, powerapps-canvas

I have a ComboBox in my powerapp that populates using data from a sharepoint list, using `Distinct(ListName, Application)`, with Application being a column of type 'Choice' from the List. This works well in terms of allowing the user to choose from the predetermined list, but I want to allow the user to type a new value into the combobox and for that value to be added to the list of possible choices in the Application column upon submission, as well as ensure it's properly in the data submitted with the new entry. I believe this is possible in the desktop application, but I'm operating from the web app so I'm looking for a workaround. Any help is greatly appreciated!